# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#document' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'DIV'

Tags: javascript

После

```
parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingSVGSource, "image/svg+xml");
// returns a SVGDocument, which also is a Document.
```

получил javascript объект `#document`,
как присоединять этот `#document` к `dom` элементу ?

После appendChild  получаю ошибку

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#document' may not be inserted inside nodes of type 'DIV'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SVGDocument.documentElement`

```js
const svgString = `
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30"/>
</svg>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const svg = parser.parseFromString(svgString, "image/svg+xml");

document.body.appendChild(svg.documentElement);
```

В примере выше `svg` это объект документа, мы не можем вставить в `DOM` документ, нам нужен дом-узел - `Node`.

`svg.documentElement` или `svg.rootElement` это самый верхний узел.

Comment: Если возможно объясните что именно было не так и как сработал `documentElement`

Comment: @a_mine добавил небольшое описание